# Image plotted from a FITS file with matplotlib oriented incorrectly

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, astronomy, fits

I'm having a little issue with something regarding plotting a fits image using `matplotlib`'s `imshow`. It seems that my image is flipped both horizontally and vertically. I'm sure there is something simple I am overlooking, if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

This is what my image should look like:

[image]

So, I'm loading my image as:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
#Opening/reading in my fits file
hdulist = fits.open('.../myfits.fits')
#Accessing the image data and specifying the dimensions I wish to use
my_image = hdulist[0].data[0,0:,0:]
#Plotting the image
pyplot.imshow(image_SWIFT_uvm2_plot, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=0.5)
pyplot.show()
```

This is what my image in the plot looks like (the plot is a little more complex than the code I have included, but I have given the critical lines as, hopefully, a self-sufficient code):

[image]

Those of you with keen eyes should see that the image has flipped both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For FITS files the convention is that the origin is at the lower left hand corner of the image, so you need to use `origin='lower'` (by default Matplotlib uses `origin='upper'`).

Comment: Found this out late last night, works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention that for plotting astronomical images with Python, there are two great packages which allow to plot the world coordinates: WCSAxes and APLpy.

Comment: Yeh, I'm currently working on implementing APLpy within my gridspec layout setup.

Comment: This is more informative given the context at hand than my own answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the astropy module, but I know that PyFITS opens the image data as a NumPy array (and from what I'm [reading](http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyfits), astropy.io.fits has inherited the functionality of PyFITS anyway, so it should work the same way). If that is the case, then you may use [`numpy.fliplr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html) and [`numpy.flipud`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) to flip the array to your desired orientation. Just replace the line

```
pyplot.imshow(image_SWIFT_uvm2_plot, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=0.5)
```

with

```
import numpy as np
pyplot.imshow(np.fliplr(np.flipud(image_SWIFT_uvm2_plot)), cmap='gray',
    vmin=0, vmax=0.5)
```

Alternatively, you could do a little linear algebra to flip it, or just note that performing both of these flips is the same as using [`np.rot90`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) twice

```
pyplot.imshow(np.rot90(image_SWIFT_uvm2_plot, k=2), cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=0)
```