# How to stop fits files from being imported upside down python

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy, fits

When importing a fits image in python it gets imported upside down.

This is the code i'm using:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io get fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = fits.getdata('myimage.fits')

plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
plt.colorbar()
```

Again I just want to view the image and it opens upside down. When I open it in an image viewer I have on my computer it looks fine so I know I didn't save it upside down. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Exactly the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072405/how-to-stop-matplotlib-from-inverting-fits-files-when-plotting from a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image plotted from a FITS file with matplotlib oriented incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778651/image-plotted-from-a-fits-file-with-matplotlib-oriented-incorrectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the keyword argument origin= 'lower' or origin='upper' in your call to imshow.